# Why won't this Form data send to the next page?

Tags: php, html

I am not experienced with PHP in the slightest, but this form should send information from the page you select it on to another page:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="nextpage.php">
   <select name="form">
     <option value="bike">BMX 3000</option> 
   </select>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The next page has this code:

```
<html>
    <body>
       <center>You selected <?php echo $_POST['form']; ?></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Would love some help!

Comment: only `<select>` uses name attributes, not `<option>`. Yet that should still work.

Comment: But it doesn't xD

Comment: I see, well someone gave you an answer below. There isn't much else I can add here.

Comment: Do you reach the next page? Try adding <?php print_r($_POST); ?> and post the results here.

Comment: Or you could post your entire script were the form is in and the processing script, perhaps the error is somewhere else

Comment: Yes I reach the next page but it does not show the php and I tried that and it did not do anything as well.. and this is the entire script, i have a page called nextpage.php and the first page is a page called home.html

Comment: Tell me @NicholasAlbertson on the second page, what *do* you see when viewing the HTML source; "code"? I have a feeling what's really the issue here.

Comment: I will update the question with it.

Comment: the update doesn't tell us much and you didn't reply to my comment above. Up until that you describe exactly what's being shown in the HTML source as I asked, your question will remain unanswered. You will need to ping me back here @NicholasAlbertson as I did for you, I can't stay here much longer. Good luck.

Comment: What do you mean? thats literally all the code there is.

Comment: Theres 2 files in a folder, one called home.html with the form element in it and another called nextpage.php with the second part of the code in it @Fred-ii-

Comment: what result do you expect in the nextpage.php? 'You selected bike' or 'You selected BMX 3000'?

Comment: You selected bmx 3000 @manian

Answer (score -1, accepted):

page.html,

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="nextpage.php">
    <select name="form">
        <option value="Bike">BMX 3000</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

nextpage.php,

```
<body>
    <center>You selected <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[form]); ?></center>
</body>
```

Output,

You selected Bike

Comment: I will try this out when I can and let you know what hapoens. Thanks.

Comment: If you want output - You selected bmx 3000, the value of option tag should be bmx 3000, not 'Bike'. <option value="BMX 3000">BMX 3000</option>

Comment: Okay so I tried this and i still recieve no php on the other page where the bmx 3000 should be is just a blank spot. Im so lost. And my code is yours exactly.

Comment: Then what could my problem be?

Comment: Im going to accept your answer because I feel like this should work but for whatever reason something else is wring on my end.

Comment: As htmlspecialchars is supported in PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, the code should work with all php versions. I am sorry, I couldn't figure it out. Make sure that <select name="form"> and $_POST[form] have same value 'form'.

Comment: Yeah I made sure of that aswell as tried to copy and paste your code and neither work, I just don't understand why, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You will get this text at nextpage.php:

"You selected Array ( [form] => bike )"

Are you expecting "Array(bike->BMX 3000)" ?

OPTION tag need not name attribute. Only one attribute can select and it's name is SELECT's name. The value will be VALUE attribute's value.

Your "BMX 3000" for display only.